# c# - How to pass the data from grid view to report Viewer?

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview, reportviewer

Staff gave some research, but still could not understand how to do, I have little knowledge in C #.

I have a grid view where I add several items that were in it, now I need to move these items to a report View report.

I do not know how to do, it would be better to pass all data grid for vestments or pick up the item ids of each output as they are distinct values ​​(eg, are items that correspond to various outputs) and make a query and bring the data to the report ... what would be the most feasible??

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site, please can you include more technical background in your question?  Including some code is always good, and a description of the data structures that you're using would help inform the answerers..

Comment: Friend I have an application in C #, where I have 2 gridviews and have a filter by date, choose a date and first GridView1 shows all items listed in the chosen date, then I have a button that adds the chosen item selected from GridView1 past data for GridView2 here is working. Now need to pass values ​​GridView2 to ReportView.

Comment: I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're in Local-Processing Mode since no further information was supplied.

**ReportDataSource** is how you **supply data to a ReportViewer Control** in **local-mode**.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251736(v=vs.90).aspx

Now after going to GridView Page on MSDN,
I found that **GridView.DataSourceObject implements IDataSource**. (Which is a parameter option for creating a ReportDataSource).

Meaning you should be able to **create a ReportDataSource** to supply to your ReportViewer Control, just create the ReportDataSource (Rds) **from your GridView** like so,

```
ReportDataSource Rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSetName", GridView.DataSourceObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code for viewing data in report viewer with gridview data.

```
        int id =Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report1.rdlc");

        DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSourceObject;
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DatasetName", dt);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        }
```

[Reference code](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2014/06/create-rdlc-reports-using-report-viewer.html)